# How do I evade and fall back from the Cloudburst Tank?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I've tried half a dozen times, but I can only destroy three of the four coolant targets on the Cloudburst Tank. As soon as I destroy one, I run for my life, but the tank is always right behind me! Eventually I lose it, but it takes so long, it has chewed up a bunch of the Batmobile's armor, and the chase ends in the slow-mo, fiery death of the Batmobile.

**How can I evade and fall back quickly after attacking the Cloudburst Tank?**

Comment: I wasn't able to find a trick to do this actually.  I had to remind myself to get out of the "battle mode" of the batmobile and speed away sometimes though.  I guess it's best to get to a pace with a bunch of alleys to try to get out of his sight, but I know he always seems right behind you anyway!  (Just keep trying)!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a strategy I've used to defeat the Cloudburst Tank with relative ease.  This strategy requires an upgrade though: **Cobra Lure**.

First things first, destroy all Cobra Drones first.  You want to make sure you eliminate all obstacles so they don't get in the way.

Next, do your best to lure the Cloudburst Tank into the canal.  The goal here is to prevent it from being able to chase you down since that's one of its bigger (and scarier) strengths.  It will have a hard time navigating in and out of the canals so try to keep yourself and the Cloudburst separated.

I don't have a save where I can revisit the battle but this is the area in the canals that you will want to lure it:

[image: map location]

[image: overview]

Use your lure by shooting in at the ground or walls around the tank in the direction you want it to go.

Once you get it down there, position yourself overlooking the area on the southern side of the canal.  There should be some cars and a small set of stairs there (as pictured in the second screenshot).

Then let em have it shooting at the weak spot one shot at a time.  Once you shoot it, it will immediately try to go after you.  Once it does, start shooting at the ground at the corner to lure it back.  You'll never have to worry about outrunning it again.

Take care and avoid any shots it may take at you.  Missiles will never go high enough and will always hit the side of the canal, but it's electrical blasts can still get you.

Just repeat the process until you eventually defeat it.

---

If you have not gotten the Cobra Lure, you'll have a tougher time but the strategy is still pretty much the same.  Try to keep the fights around the canals, and stay away from open streets.

If it is over a bridge, go into the canal and shoot at it to get its attention.  When it gets into the canal, make sure you're out of the canal and shoot at it again.  Just make sure that you're close enough to a ramp or it's far enough away from one before you shoot, you'll need to keep your escape route open.

That corner is a good safe spot do to this as you'll have additional ways into the canal.  You can go down the ramp or just fall into it.

Comment: That looks like a good strategy. Unfortunately, I've only got one upgrade point, and I'm locked out of side quests, so maybe in New Game+?

Comment: Ooh, that'll be tough, but not impossible. It'll be harder to lure him there but that's still my suggestion for an easier time. In my first playthough (I always start on hard), I also didn't get the Cobra Lure. But the strategy overall is still the same. The goal is to prevent it from chasing you down. If you can keep the canals and bridges between you and the Cloudburst, you'll have an easier time surviving.

Comment: Other people I've read are having an easier time with phase 2 of the battle by just standing their ground against it. The missiles it shoots can all be shot down. I'll have to try that out if I ever get a chance to play that battle again (without having to play through the rest of the game). I wonder if that really works even in phase 1, I hear it's supposed to be easy to dodge the electrical blasts.

Comment: If I ever get there, I'll try that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to take down the CloudBurst tank without Cobra Lure or even using the canals, provided you are quick to *transform back to car mode* and sprint out of there, and know the map well enough to not get caught in dead ends. The usual tricks apply - shoot from near a corner, duck back behind it to lose initial LOS, transform, and book it; remember to use your "side jets" to dodge any crosshairs if necessary.

Comment: How do I use side jets in care mode? I thought those were restricted to battle mode.

Comment: If you've ever done the missions to chase down APCs, you might have noticed a HUD note giving the command to quickly shift to one side or the other (a short distance - think roughly 1/2 of a lane change). That's what you do. On the PC, I think it's holding down left or right arrow and tapping space.